# wrong conversion of a string to a variable

Tags: javascript

kindly assist me to know why when i call a function and pass a parameter using a string in its 'raw form' i get the right output but when i assign it to a variable first i get a different output.

i want to convert CSV string into a  JavaScript array of arrays. when i pass the parameter in console in its raw form i.e `console.log(relay('a;b\nc;d', ';'))` i get the right results which is an array but when i convert the string into a variable called dat i get the wrong array [";"] which is basically the second part of my string.

```js
relay = (dat, delimiter = ',', tested = false) =>
  dat
  .split('\n')
  .slice(tested ? dat.indexOf('\n') + 1 : 0);
let dat = ('a;b\nc;d', ';');
console.log(relay(dat)); // [";"]
console.log(relay('a;b\nc;d', ';'));
```

When i call the function using `dat` variable I get the output as `[";"]`

When I call the function as `console.log(relay('a;b\nc;d', ';'))` I get 
the right output  `["a;b", "c;d"]`

​

the result i expect is an array of arrays `[["a;b"], ["c;d"]]`

Comment: You never split by your `delimiter`, you only split the input into lines?

Comment: indenting in this code makes it hard to grasp

Comment: no clue what `delimiter` does since the expected ouput does not seem to actually care.

Comment: @epascarello Looks like he may be developing it incrementally, and that parameter will be used in the future.

Comment: To get the output like that it would have to look like `'a;b\nc;d'.split(/\n/).map(s => [s])` no clue what the other logic is used for. If you are trying to split it again... `'a;b\nc;d'.split(/\n/).map(s => s.split(';'))`

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
let dat = ('a;b\nc;d', ';');
```

does not do what you think. It's using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which just returns its right operand, so it's equivalent to

```
let data = ';';
```

You could assign an array to the variable, and then spread it in the call.

```js
relay = (dat, delimiter = ',', tested = false) =>
  dat
  .split('\n')
  .slice(tested ? dat.indexOf('\n') + 1 : 0);
let dat = ['a;b\nc;d', ';'];
console.log(relay(...dat));
console.log(relay('a;b\nc;d', ';'));
```

Comment: This answer is exactly like mine, but includes more useful information! It should be selected, IMO

Answer (score 1):

```
function log(s1, s2) {
  console.log(s1, s2);
}

let str1 = 'a';
let str2 = 'b';
log(str1, str2); // 'a' 'b'

let str = ('a', 'b');
console.log(str); // 'b'
log(str); // 'b' undefined
```

Notice that you cannot assign two value to one variable and use it to pass as arguments to a function. To achieve what you want, you can either use two variables, one for `dat` and one for `delimiter`, call the function with these two variables.

```
let dat = 'a;b\nc;d';
let delimiter = ';';
console.log(relay(dat, delimiter));
```

Another way is to use an object with multiple properties, e.g.

```
relay = ({ dat, delimiter = ',', tested = false }) => {
  dat
    .split('\n')
    .slice(tested ? dat.indexOf('\n') + 1 : 0);

  return dat;
}

let config = {
  dat: 'a;b\nc;d', 
  delimiter: ';'
};
console.log(relay(config));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `dat`:

```
let dat = ('a;b\nc;d', ';');
```

You should try to print `dat`, so you can see what it looks like:

```
console.log(dat);
```

You will see that dat is `';'` - this is because of the relatively obscure [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which simply selects the value after the last comma. In your case, `';`' occurs after the last comma.

Answer (score 0):

i have noticed that the default parameter is also being passed with the comma operator, i.e the string is not passed as a whole ('a;b\nc;d', ';');

Comment: It looks like this answer is simply providing additional information about your question. If you have more to add, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57661146/edit) and add it, rather than posting an answer. :)